# JFrame never renders if program is only interacted with through doClick();

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am writing an Othello game using Swing, here's the general code: (The snippet does not include the cases for game end/same player goes again, it's just the basic gameplay loop.)
View/Controller:

```
public class OthelloGUI extends JFrame {
    JSquare[][] board;
    final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
    OthelloModel model;
    
    public OthelloGUI(OthelloModel m) {
        model = m;
        
        /* Window size, etc... */
        setLayout(new GridLayout(BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE));

        //add 8x8 buttons to GUI
        ActionListener ml = new MoveListener();
        board = new JSquare[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                getContentPane.add(board[i][j] = new JSquare(new Point(i, j)));
                board[i][j].addActionListener(ml);
            }
        }
        update();
    }

    void update() {

        //update GUI to reflect last move
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                //changes the JButton's text based on who owns it on the model's board
                board[i][j].setText(model.getOwner(i, j).view());
            }
        }
        
        //best place (I think) to have AI move is after the last move is processed
        if (model.getCurrentPlayerType() == PlayerType.AI) {

            //Computer player finds its next move, and clicks that button
            int[] bestMove = GreedyAI.findMove(model);
            board[bestMove[0]][bestMove[1]].doCLick();
        }
    }

    static class JSquare extends JButton {
        java.awt.Point p;
        JSquare (Point p) {this.p = p;}
    }

    class MoveListener implements ActionListener {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            JSquare sq = (JSquare) e.getSource();

            //places the piece on the model's "board" and flips all applicable pieces
            int result = model.placeDisk(s.p, model.getCurrentColor());
            
            if (result == 0) {//move executes successfully
                update();
            }
            //otherwise... (illegal move, game end, same player again, etc...) 
        }
    }
}

enum Owner {
    NONE, BLACK, WHITE;

    public String view() {
        return this == BLACK ? "B" : this == WHITE ? "W" : ""
    }
}
```

This code executes fine if I start a `Human v Human` or `Human v AI` game, however, if I start an `AI v AI` game, the GUI never renders. I get the popup box for game setup, and the popup for the game end and who won, but the main `ContentPane` with the board never renders, so I don't see what moves the AI make.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Does your AI vs AI game just complete so quickly that there isn't time to see the window open? Have you tried adding a 1 second delay between moves?

Comment: I tried adding a delay, both in `doClick` (making it press the button for longer) and a `Thread.sleep()` before the AI goes, neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AI is automated. The human is .. not.

- When the human is playing a human the code must wait for the human to make each turn. It must be event driven.
- When the human plays the AI, the AI is automated but the code must still wait for events from the human.
- But when the AI plays the AI the *entire process* is left to the code and this leads to the EDT being blocked.

Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.